# will older versions of swift work with newer iOS versions?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm a newbie iOS developer and I'm trying to wrap my head on how compatibility works in iOS development. So because I'm using an older MacBook Pro. I'm running Xcode 9.4.1 which comes with swift 4. So what I'm trying to figure out is, will an app developed with swift 4 run iOS (12.2- 13.2) and  will that app also run on older versions i.e iOS 10 ..  Thanks for any explanation !

Comment: This might be helpful : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Version_comparison_table

Comment: Keep in mind, `Starting April 2020, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 13 SDK or later, included in Xcode 11 or later`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift versions are irrelevant to what iOS version you are developing for. However, Xcode version does matter, since the newest iOS runtimes are only available in the newest Xcode versions.

This doesn't necessarily mean that if you use an older Xcode version, your app wouldn't run on newer version, but you couldn't test your app on newer versions directly from Xcode. Moreover, Apple doesn't allow uploads to the AppStore using old Xcode versions.

From March 2019, only apps built with Xcode 10 are accepted, while from April 2020, only apps built with Xcode 11 will be accepted to the AppStore, as described in the [AppStore Submissions](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/submissions/) page.

So if you want to be able to release your app, you'll need to upgrade your Xcode (and hence your laptop as well).

Comment: Thank you so much David ! This is really concise and understandable. I should probably start thinking of how to become an android developer